# Show and hide user default location marker on Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to hide and then show user location setting *mapView.isMyLocationEnabled* to "true" and "false" accordingly, but I'm experiencing *mapView.myLocation* being set to nil after first switch from true to false user default position blue dot marker never appears again. Is there any way to enable and disable default user location presentation?

Comment: Why don't you use a custom image, get coordinates from your location manager and then put your custom image marker on your current location. Show/hide that custom marker?

Comment: default marker has cool presenting features, but I will use custom one in case there won't be any way to accomplish switch back to show user location again

Answer (score 0):

MapView.myLocation must always have a CLLocation to display. If it nil when you updateLocation then set it a default CLLocation that you want.

Comment: it's a get-only property, haven't found the way and place where to update it

Comment: but the reason i'm not seing user location is for sure nil in myLocation